# Matplotlib drawing labels from twin axis on top of label of original axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, twinx

I have a problem in that Im drawing a plot of 7 moving averages (p1, dataframe) using the left y-axis. On the right y-axis Im drawing the data the MAs are made from (pidx, also dataframe). Being time-series, they share the x-axis.

Im drawing 2 plots, top and bottom. The bottom one is ok, the top one is giving me trouble in that the 7 labels of p1 are written correctly for the left y-axis, top left. However, the (single) label of the right y-axis, pidx, is drawn directly over the first label of the left y-axis.

Im still new to plotting and have tried several options, such as putting it bottom left instead of top, but keep gettng errors. My code might be a mess, so if someone could suggest the "neatest" way to define labels when using twin axes Id be really grateful. Thanks.

Heres what Im working with:

```
p1 = above_below_ma_df.tail(lookback)
p2 = t2108.tail(lookback)
# p4 = above_below_ma_df['$>MA40'].tail(lookback)
pidx = idx.tail(lookback)

# Create subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(15, 10))

# Plot MAs on top subplot
#################################################################################
axs[0].plot(p1.index, p1, linewidth=1)
axs[0].set_ylabel('% stocks above MAs')
axs[0].set_xlabel('Date')
axs[0].set_title(f"{code} - No. stocks above/below MAs")
axs[0].legend(labels=p1.columns, loc='upper left')  # Use column names for legend labels

# Add index to other axis of top subplot
axs0_twin = axs[0].twinx()
axs0_twin.plot(p1.index, pidx, 'black', linewidth=2, label=code)

# Set y-axis label at the lower left corner
#axs0_twin.ylabel(code, loc='bottom left')
#axs0_twin.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.1, 0.5)  # Adjust the coordinates as needed
#axs0_twin.set_ylabel(code, color='black')

# axs0_twin.set_ylabel(code, color='black')
# axs0_twin.legend(labels=code, loc='lower left',color='black')

# Plot T2108 vs Close on lower subplot
#################################################################################
axs[1].plot(p2.index, p2, color='b', alpha=0.7, label='T2108')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Date')
axs[1].set_ylabel('T2108-(%>40MA)', color='b')
# Add a horizontal dotted line to show where fundos might be
axs[1].axhline(y=15, color='b', linestyle='--')
axs[1].axhline(y=85, color='b', linestyle='--')

# Add index to other axis
axs1_twin = axs[1].twinx()
axs1_twin.plot(p2.index, pidx, 'black', label=code)
axs1_twin.set_ylabel(code, color='black')

# Combine legends for both subplots
lines0, labels0 = axs[0].get_legend_handles_labels()
lines0_twin, labels0_twin = axs0_twin.get_legend_handles_labels()
axs0_twin.legend(lines0 + lines0_twin, labels0 + labels0_twin, loc='upper left')

lines1, labels1 = axs[1].get_legend_handles_labels()
lines1_twin, labels1_twin = axs1_twin.get_legend_handles_labels()
axs1_twin.legend(lines1 + lines1_twin, labels1 + labels1_twin, loc='upper left')

plt.show()

return above_below_ma_df, t2108
```

Comment: This question isn't answerable by anyone else because you did not share any data or show what the plot looks like. As is, this question is not useful for future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

So after some messing I managed to get what I wanted, the right y-axis lable neatly below the list of left y-axis labels.

Couldnt find out how to delete the question, so I thought Id post the answer in case it helps anyone else.

```
p1 = above_below_ma_df.tail(lookback) # df with 7 moving average columns 
pidx = idx.tail(lookback) # df with column of original data

# Create subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(15, 10))

# Plot MAs on top subplot # Lower subplot not shown here

# p1 columns on left y-axis
axs[0].plot(p1.index, p1, linewidth=1, label=p1.columns)
# pidx column on twin y-axis on right
axs0_twin = axs[0].twinx()
axs0_twin.plot(p1.index, pidx, linewidth=2, color='black', label=code)

# Adding the x-axis with dates
axs[0].set_xlabel('Date')

# Adding labels for both y-axes
axs[0].set_ylabel('% stocks above MAs')
axs0_twin.set_ylabel(code, color='black')

# Combine legends for both subplots
lines0, labels0 = axs[0].get_legend_handles_labels()
lines0_twin, labels0_twin = axs0_twin.get_legend_handles_labels()
axs0_twin.legend(lines0 + lines0_twin, labels0 + labels0_twin, loc='upper left')

# Add title for plot
axs[0].set_title(f"{code} - No. stocks above/below MAs")
```